# Unpacking Characters from an Integer

Tags: c

I'm trying to update 16 bit code to 32 bit code and unpack a given unsigned int to 4 characters. It's working alright except in two spots. I just started with this concept so I'm not strong with it yet. Can anyone please explain why two of the characters don't show up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// prototypes
void unpackCharacters32(char *aPtr, char *bPtr, char *cPtr, char *dPtr, unsigned int pack);
void displayBits(unsigned int value);
int main(void)
{
 // display bits of packed
 unsigned int packed = 1818978115; // initialize packed value
 puts("The packed character representation is:");
 displayBits(packed);
 char a; // first character unpacked
 char b;// second character unpacked
 char c;
 char d;
 unpackCharacters32(&a, &b, &c,&d, packed);
 printf("\nThe unpacked characters are \'%c\',\'%c\',\'%c\' and \'%c\'\n", a, b,c,d);
 displayBits(a);
 displayBits(b);
 displayBits(c);
 displayBits(d);
}
// unpack two characters from pack
void unpackCharacters32(char *aPtr, char *bPtr, char *cPtr, char *dPtr, unsigned int pack)
{
 unsigned int mask1=4278190080; // mask for first character
 unsigned int mask2=16711680; // mask for second character
 unsigned int mask3=65280;
 unsigned int mask4=255;

 *aPtr = (pack & mask1)>>8; // separate first character
 *bPtr = (pack & mask2)>>8; // separate second character
 *cPtr = (pack & mask3)>>8;
 *dPtr = (pack & mask4);
}
// display the bits of value
void displayBits(unsigned int value)
{
 unsigned int displayMask = 1 << 31; // bit mask
 printf("%7u = ", value);
 // loop through bits
 for (unsigned int c = 1; c <= 32; c++) {
 value & displayMask ? putchar('1') : putchar('0');
 value <<= 1; // shift value 1 bit to the left

 if (c % 8 == 0) { // print a space
 putchar(' ');
 }
 }
 putchar('\n');
}
```

here's what its supposed to look like

Pack: 1818978115➔ output should be 'l', 'k', 'g', and 'C'

here's what I'm getting

```
The unpacked characters are '','','g' and 'C'
      0 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
      0 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
    103 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100111 
     67 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000011
```

Comment: Giving your masks decimal values you are making it really difficult to read. Aren't you aware of hexadecimal notation? Anyway, without even trying to understand their values, shifting right by `8` bits for *every* packed character (well, except the last one) does not seem right at all.

Comment: Sorry, those are the masks I have to work with. The base concept is pointers I had to update a given code so I don't know a lot about the bit values

Comment: It's easier if you write it like `unsigned int mask1 = 0xff << 24;`

Comment: Whoa, may be well worth spacing your code a bit more to make it more readable (especially for older eyes). Minimum of 2-space indent and consider spacing around the operator or assignment, e.g. `unsigned int mask4 = 255;` or `*cPtr = (pack & mask3) >> 8;`. This is completely *Up To You* and is just a suggestion based on 30+ years or reading code (and having older eyes....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not shifting correctly. Since `mask1` matches the high-order byte, you have to shift 3 bytes down, not just 1 byte. So it should be

```
*aPtr = (pack & mask1)>>24;
*bPtr = (pack & mask2)>>16;
*cPtr = (pack & mask3)>>8;
*dPtr = (pack & mask4);
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought about this but it kept telling me to shift 8 bits for the 4278190080 mask so I was just following it.

Comment: What was telling you that? I suspect you misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Use memcpy

```
int main(void)
{
    // display bits of packed
    unsigned int packed = 1818978115; // initialize packed value
    puts("The packed character representation is:");
    displayBits(packed);
    char a[4]; // first character unpacked
    unpackCharacters32(a, packed);
    printf("\nThe unpacked characters are \'%c\',\'%c\',\'%c\' and \'%c\'\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
    displayBits(a[0]);
    displayBits(a[1]);
    displayBits(a[2]);
    displayBits(a[3]);
}
// unpack two characters from pack

void unpackCharacters32(char *aPtr, unsigned int pack)
{
    memcpy(aPtr, &pack, sizeof(pack));
}
```

If you want to use bitshifts use HEX numbers not decimal as they digits represent exact numbers of bits (4)

BTW you do need to use any masks

```
void unpackCharacters32(char *aPtr, char *bPtr, char *cPtr, char *dPtr, unsigned int pack)
{
 
 *dPtr = pack & 0xff; // separate first character
 *cPtr = (pack >> 8) & 0xff;
 *bPtr = (pack >> 16) & 0xff;
 *aPtr = (pack >> 24) & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: This is depending on endianness and not portable (well, *less portable* than the original).